# Why it doesn't return anything?

Tags: python-3.x

when i run the program it doesn't return the values True or False. Why that happens?

```
def esvocal(letter):
vocal = "a","e","i","o","u"
vocalup = "A","E","I","O","U" 

if letter == vocal and letter == vocalup:
    return True
else:
    return False 
esvocal("s")
esvocal("a")
```

Comment: Think about what _equality_ with `==` means here.

Comment: how can a letter both be "a" and "A"? Also, please take the time to fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: How could those things possibly *both* be true?! For that matter, how could *either*?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
def esvocal(letter):
    vocal =[ "a","e","i","o","u"]
    vocalup = ["A","E","I","O","U"]

    if letter in vocal and letter in vocalup:
        return True
    else:
        return False 
esvocal("s")
esvocal("a")
```

1. Python really cares about indentation
2. Use in instead of ==

Comment: Put the strings in an array also